# Force SSL only on certain pages with .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I'm trying to force ssl on certain pages, but also on a directory. But I am getting a page loop error. This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} dashboard
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/dashboard/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} get_started_lp.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} get_started.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Basically is someone goes to get_stared_lp or get_started or the dashboard I want SSL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never-mind. It ended up being a issue with how Rackspace handles their SSL. For more information:
http://www.wreckedmagazine.com/jasonsmall/2010/09/14/force-ssl-on-a-rackspace-folder/